# File permission gets changed after file gets downloaded on client machine

Tags: python, linux, apache, file-permissions

How to execute a file after it gets downloaded on client side,File is a python script, User dont know how to change permission of a file, How to solve this issue??

Comment: You can't (without access to the target machine). This is a security feature.

Comment: @syntonym Then how client will execute that file?

Comment: The downloading client does not want the user to simply run the script just downloaded from the internet. The basic idea: Who has no idea how to change the permission should not run a script from the internet. Too dangerous! To repeat it: It's the downloading client (web browser) that sets the permissions and there is nothing in the HTTP standard to signal the permissions as well.

Comment: @Aman Is your client on linux, windows or osx (or something different)?

Comment: @syntonym Client can on any platform, File which he will download is a python script through my server using web portal.

Answer (score 1):

Change file permissions to make it executable: `sudo chmod +x file.py`

Comment: User dont know how to change file permission, He downloaded this file as a software now he want to execute that for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try teaching them how to use chmod +x command? Or actualy even more simple it would be to change it using GUI: right click -> properties -> permissions-> pick what is needed

Comment: When we download software we dont do that, instead we install that software by executing it.

Comment: @Aman what do you mean by that? To install it you need to execute it, to execute it you need to make it executable.

Comment: @syntonym How he will install that package or software.

Comment: In previous comment by executing i mean double click.

Comment: @Aman if you provide an installer, let the client make the installer executable (e.g. with `chmod +x myinstaller`) and then execute the installer. Other ways to distribute software is the utilize packet management systems like apt-get or pip.